# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /login/ while running the server locally

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I using One To One field in Django to save some extra information about user but even afte migrating i got the issue which i mentioned in title
[**my models.py**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUNWt.png)

**the issue I got**
[issue while running server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLhSr.png)

please help if you can

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting:

```
User has no profile
```

Simply means what it says, meaning the particular `User` instance you are dealing with has no related `Profile`. Now you might be wondering why not, but that is because a `User` record can perfectly exist without a 'Profile' relation, the constraint only applies to your profiles, which cannot be created without a corresponding user record.

So if you have somehow tried linking the user to a certain profile, that means the code that is supposed to make that happen isn't doing so and from what I got from the images, you're using signals for that. But I wouldn't recommend doing so, not because signals are generally bad, but because in this case its sorta overkill, and it spreads your code too much.

What I'd suggest/recommend is to add the logic to create profile in the User creation form.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because the user does not have an associated profile in the DB.

Even though there is an OneToOne relation there doesn't a guarantee. that a user will have a profile.

So you probably need to create a profile for that user.

Also if you want to extend the user model, Ill recommend that you check out [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html). It contains more ways to achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

profile doesnt get created automatically ,you need either to add it manually or use signals so that every time a user is created a profile also is created,

if you have a profile model lets say you named it Profile

create a signals.py and add this to it:

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.dispatch import receiver

    from .models import Profile

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding `blank=True`, then why are you adding `default=''`
If you want profile picture to be mandatory, remove `blank=True`